# Homotopy category of chain complexes and its homotopy category as a dg category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I'm trying to learn about dg categories and I'm seeking for some clarifications in Keller's survey paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601185.pdf.

The category of chain complexes of modules, which I'll denote as $\mathscr{C}_{dg}$, was given as an example of a dg category, where the Hom spaces are now given by the inner Hom complexes. So when one takes the homotopy category $H^0(\mathscr{C}_{dg})$, it's stated that

> $H^0(\mathscr{C}_{dg})$ is equivalent to the category of complexes up to homotopy.

What confused me is that it seems like within $H^0(\mathscr{C}_{dg})$, the Hom spaces are now given by all chain maps modulo homotopy with *all possible cohomological grading shifts*, where as in the category of complexes up to homotopy the Hom spaces are just chain maps without the cohomological grading shifts. Can someone please clarify if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $H^0(\mathscr{C}_{dg})$, the morphisms are given by taking $H^0$ of the complex of chain maps.  Because we are taking only $H^0$ (and not cohomology in other degrees), these are homotopy classes of actual chain maps, not chain maps with a degree shift.

Comment: Ah thanks! I was thinking $H^*(\mathscr{C}_{dg})$ instead. Cheers!